# Java 1.7 - with Math.log function

Tags: java, double

I write this line in my code:

```
szo.P_POS = Math.log( ((double) (szo.talalatok_szama_POS_blokkban) / (double)(szo.osszes_talalat_szama)) );
```

Variables `szo.talalatok_szama_POS_blokkban` and `szo.osszes_talalat_szama` are `int` member of szo inner class

And when I run it, I get different value from the actual value

Example:

```
System.out.println(Math.log((double)0.6));
```

this line evaluate to -0.5108256237659907

and actual value is: -0,22184874961635636749123320202039 (Windows Calculator)

Comment: These variables have weird names..

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want a base 10 logarithm:

```
Math.log10(x);
```

Comment: i need base e logarithm because I implement a naive bayes algorithm, and I multiply very small numbers

Answer (score 1):

What base of logarithm is each version using?  Java's `Math.log` uses base e, or `ln` in common math terms.

Comment: ln x, log e x is not equal?

Comment: Why didn't they call the method `ln()`?

Comment: @user3029180: Those two are equal, but it's not clear from your question which version Windows Calculator is using.

Comment: @JasonSperske where is ln() method? how to use it?

Comment: @user3029180: I meant which version of log was being used by Windows Calculator, which appears to be base 10.  If you mean base `e`, then the Java version is correct.

Comment: @JasonSperske Wikipedia says "mathematicians usually mean natural logarithm rather than common logarithm when they write 'log'."

Comment: i'have been tricked, because windows calcultor compute with log10, and java function name log not ln